# Change '_' to ' ' doesn't work at all

Tags: c++, arrays, char

So i got simple code to change all _ to space but...it doesnt work! Any1 knows why? I have no idea

```
while (fout >> array[x][y]){
    if (array[x][y]=='_') array[x][y]==' ';
    y++;
    if (y==8) {
        y=0;
        x+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine how it doesn't work, let alone why. You may want to provide some additional context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
if (array[x][y]=='_') array[x][y]==' ';
                                  ^
```

You have two equal signs when you are attempting to set the new value.

Comment: +1, Missed it on the first reading, too

Comment: Oh ... My... God... I feel so emberassed! I'm sorry.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Hey no worries! I'm sure this kind of thing has happened to everyone from time to time.